# How to show online offline user status in pubnub using swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, pubnub

```
client.setState(["is_online": true,"user_id":uuid], forUUID: userId as! String, onChannel: "channelName") { (status) in
    if !status.isError {
      print(status)
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please provide a description of your problem. Are you receiving an error message?

Comment: If you are having issues using PubNub SDK, please file support ticket with [PubNub Support](https://support.pubnub.com) instead of posting vague question here. We will answer your questions.

Answer (score 1):

User presence functionality can be implemented using the [PubNub Presence feature](https://www.pubnub.com/products/presence/?devrel_so=how-to-show-online-offline-user-status-in-pubnub-using-swift-4). Go to your [PubNub Admin Dashboard](https://admin.pubnub.com/?devrel_so=how-to-show-online-offline-user-status-in-pubnub-using-swift-4) and enable the presence feature for your API keys.

Now on the client side you can check which users are online with the `whereNowUUID` method, which is described thoroughly in the [Swift PubNub Presence Documentation](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/swift/presence?devrel_so=how-to-show-online-offline-user-status-in-pubnub-using-swift-4)

```
self.client.whereNowUUID(self.client.uuid(), withCompletion: { (result, status) in

    if status == nil {

        // Handle downloaded presence 'where now' information using: result.data.channels
    }
    else {

        /**
         Handle presence audit error. Check 'category' property
         to find out possible reason because of which request did fail.
         Review 'errorData' property (which has PNErrorData data type) of status
         object to get additional information about issue.

         Request can be resent using: status.retry()
         */
    }
})
```